# Como eliminar elementos de una lista de listas en Haskell?

Tags: haskell

no tengo mucha experiencia en haskell, no se si podrian ayudarme a resolver este ejercicio.

Dada una lista de listas eliminar las listas que contengan un numero par, y concatenar las listas resultantes en una nueva lista.

Ejemplo:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 5], [], [7]]  -->  [3, 5, 7]
```

la firma de la función es esta:

```hs
conCat :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
```

De antemano gracias.

Comment: ¿Y cuál ha sido el problema que te has encontrado? ¿Tienes problemas para filtras las listas de número par?¿No sabes _concatenar_ una lista de listas? Si no sabes por dónde empezar, míra la documentación de `Data.List`.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma en la que lo podrías hacer es así:

```hs
conCat :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
conCat xss = concat $ filter (all odd) xss
```

La parte de `filter (all odd) xss` elimina las listas que tienen algún elemento par, (`(all odd)` es lo mismo que `(not . any even)`, `concat` concatena el resto de los elementos y `$` es la aplicación de una función, que se usa para ahorrar paréntesis, para no usarlo se podría haber escrito así:

```hs
conCat xss = concat (filter (all odd) xss)
```